# Login time on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, login, time

If I enter the wrong password, it rejects the password immediately but on entering the right password it takes a longer time to validate it. One the first login, this is possibly due to the startup process but it happens even when I login after standby. Why does this happen?

I am using Windows 7 Professional x64.

Comment: What does the computer show while you're claiming it's validating the login?

Comment: nothing. the password field is frozen, then after a couple of seconds it logs in.